# OmniFaces 3.4.1 won't deploy in WildFly 16 or 18

Tags: jsf, omnifaces, jboss-weld

I have successfully used OmniFaces 3.2 for a number of years with no issues.

However I can't deploy 3.4.1 to WildFly 18. Tried with 16 too.

- Weld 3.1.3.Final
- CDI 2.0
- JBoss WildFly 18.0.1.Final
- Java openjdk 13.0.2
- Gradle 6.2.1
- Undertow 2.0.27.Final
- Mojarra 2.3.9.SP04

Error:

> 07:33:31,413 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7)
>   WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment GoStopHandleWAR.war
>   07:33:31,533 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan
>   'Infinity Minus ONE +2' 9.4.16.Final 07:33:31,610 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-000900: 3.1.3
>   (Final) 07:33:31,821 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread
>   Pool -- 88) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2)
>   Service
>   'GoStopHandle.ear/GoStopHandleJAR.jar#goStopHandleMongoDBPersistenceUnit'
>   07:33:31,850 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.impl.DatastoreProviderInitiator]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) OGM000016: NoSQL Datastore provider:
>   org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider
>   07:33:31,917 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 83) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from
>   ejb container 07:33:31,957 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) OGM001201: Connecting to MongoDB at
>   127.0.0.1:27017 with a timeout set at 10000 millisecond(s) 07:33:31,980 INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.cluster] (ServerService Thread
>   Pool -- 88) Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017],
>   mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN,
>   serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500} 07:33:31,980
>   INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.cluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88)
>   Adding discovered server 127.0.0.1:27017 to client view of cluster
>   07:33:32,005 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) OGM001207: Connecting to Mongo
>   database named [goStopHandleDB]. 07:33:32,014 INFO 
>   [org.mongodb.driver.cluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) Cluster
>   description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
>   07:33:32,031 INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.connection]
>   (cluster-ClusterId{value='5e71cecb28c1943f3b849360',
>   description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017) Opened connection
>   [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:24}] to 127.0.0.1:27017
>   07:33:32,037 INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.cluster]
>   (cluster-ClusterId{value='5e71cecb28c1943f3b849360',
>   description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017) Monitor thread successfully
>   connected to server with description
>   ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE,
>   state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 2,
>   3]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216,
>   logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=3448405}
>   07:33:32,038 INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.cluster]
>   (cluster-ClusterId{value='5e71cecb28c1943f3b849360',
>   description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017) Discovered cluster type of
>   STANDALONE 07:33:32,050 INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.connection]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) Opened connection
>   [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:25}] to 127.0.0.1:27017
>   07:33:32,183 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.GridDialectInitiator] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 88) OGM000017: Grid Dialect:
>   org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.BatchOperationsDelegator 07:33:32,185
>   INFO  [org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.GridDialectInitiator]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) Grid dialect logs are disabled
>   07:33:32,188 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.GridDialectInitiator] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 88) OGM000017: Grid Dialect:
>   org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.BatchOperationsDelegator 07:33:32,188
>   INFO  [org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.GridDialectInitiator]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) Grid dialect logs are disabled
>   07:33:32,195 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 88) HHH000400: Using dialect:
>   org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.OgmDialect 07:33:32,202 WARN 
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) HHH000342: Could not obtain
>   connection to query metadata : null 07:33:32,203 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88)
>   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.OgmDialect
>   07:33:32,206 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB
>   creation as connection was null 07:33:32,214 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 88) Envers integration enabled? : true 07:33:32,580
>   INFO  [org.hibernate.search.engine.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool
>   -- 88) HSEARCH000034: Hibernate Search 5.10.1.Final 07:33:32,581 INFO  [org.hibernate.ogm.cfg.impl.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88)
>   OGM000001: Hibernate OGM 5.4.1.Final 07:33:32,972 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-000146:
>   BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(AnnotatedType) used for class
>   com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper is deprecated from CDI 1.1!
>   07:33:33,010 INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-8)
>   MicroProfile: Metrics activated 07:33:33,324 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 7) WELD-000167: Class
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher is annotated with
>   @RequestScoped but it does not declare an appropriate constructor
>   therefore is not registered as a bean! 07:33:33,571 SEVERE
>   [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.flow] (MSC service thread
>   1-8) Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra 07:33:33,575
>   SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application.view]
>   (MSC service thread 1-8) Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for
>   Mojarra 07:33:33,657 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service
>   thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."GoStopHandle.ear".WeldStartService:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."GoStopHandle.ear".WeldStartService: Failed to
>   start service     at
>   org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) Caused by:
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 5
>   exceptions: Exception 0 :
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous
>   dependencies for type SocketSessionManager with qualifiers @Default
>   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private
>   org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketPushContextProducer.socketSessions   at
>   org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketPushContextProducer.socketSessions(SocketPushContextProducer.java:0)
>   Possible dependencies: 
>     - Managed Bean [class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketSessionManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
>     - Managed Bean [class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketSessionManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
>
> at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:386)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:290)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:143)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:164)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:526)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:64)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)  at
>   org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
>   Exception 1 : org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException:
>   WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type SocketSessionManager with
>   qualifiers @Default   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField]
>   @Inject private
>   org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketChannelManager.socketSessions   at
>   org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketChannelManager.socketSessions(SocketChannelManager.java:0)
>   Possible dependencies: 
>     - Managed Bean [class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketSessionManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
>     - Managed Bean [class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketSessionManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
>
> at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:386)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:290)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:143)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:164)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:526)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:64)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.3.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)  at
>   org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)

Comment: Basically, your build or server's temp dir is dirty. Cleanup it. See the dupe.

Comment: @BalusC Cleaned and all is working fine: OmniFaces 3.4.1, Weld 3.1.3.Final & CDI 2.0, JBoss WildFly 18.0.1.Final, Undertow 2.0.27.Final, Mojarra 2.3.9.SP04, Faces 2.3, & PrimeFace 7.0.12.

Comment: Well done -----